# spark error: spark.read.format("org.apache.spark.csv")

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am getting the following error after firing the command from spark-shell

```
scala> val df1 = spark.read.format("org.apache.spark.csv").option("inferSchema", true).option("header",true).option("delimiter", ",").csv("/user/mailtosudiptabiswa
s7917/src_files/movies_data_srcfile_sess06_01.csv")

<console>:21: error: not found: value spark
       val df1 = spark.read.format("org.apache.spark.csv").option("inferSchema", true).option("header",true).option("delimiter", ",").csv("/user/mailtosudiptabiswas7917/src_files/movies_data_srcfile_sess06_01.csv")
```

Do I need to `import` something `explicitly`.

Please help with the complete command set

Thanks.

Comment: Try `csv` instead of `org.apache.spark.csv` . It should work.

Comment: Same error:
scala> val df1 = spark.read.format("csv").option("inferSchema", true).option("header",true).option("delimiter", ",").csv("/user/mailtosudiptabiswas7917/src_files/m
ovies_data_srcfile_sess06_01.csv")
<console>:22: error: not found: value spark
       val df1 = spark.read.format("csv").option("inferSchema", true).option("header",true).option("delimiter", ",").csv("/user/mailtosudiptabiswas7917/src_files/m
ovies_data_srcfile_sess06_01.csv")

Comment: version of spark you are using?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are using the old version of spark, You need to use the spark2.x or higher and import the implicits as

```
import spark.implicits._
```

And then

```
val df1 = spark.read.format("csv").option("inferSchema", true).option("header",true).option("delimiter", ",").csv("path")
```

Comment: spark-shell provides a SparkSession "spark" out of the box.

Comment: yeah but it doesn't import the inplicits

Comment: the original error states that "error: not found: value spark". I suspect that code for Spark2 is being used in a Spark1 spark-shell (where there is no SparkSession, but only a SparkContext sc). Given that error, your edited answer still wouldn't work.

Comment: yes you are right, she has older version, I will update the answer

Answer (score 0):

You aren't even getting a `SparkSession`.  You are using an older version of Spark it seems, and you should use the `SQlContext` and also you need to include the external databricks csv library when you start spark shell...

```
$SPARK_HOME/bin/spark-shell --packages com.databricks:spark-csv_2.11:1.5.0
```

and then from within the spark shell...

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext

val sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc)
val df = sqlContext.read
    .format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
    .option("header", "true") // Use first line of all files as header
    .option("inferSchema", "true") // Automatically infer data types
    .load("cars.csv")
```

You can see more info about it [here](https://github.com/databricks/spark-csv)